# mysql : bining a column data

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a column data in MySQL server like this

```
Id     My_Column
 1       2
 2       122
 3       311
 4       555
 5       4
 6       305
```

I'd like to create a statement that I can execute with `select <something> from my_table`, the statement will group data in `My_Column` by bins

Something like this

```
 Id     My_Column  Bins
 1       2           1
 2       122         2
 3       311         3
 4       555         4
 5       4           1
 6       305         3
 7       155         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` expression to classify the rows.

```
select id, my_column,
case when my_column < 100 and my_column >=1 then 1
     when my_column < 200 and my_column >=100 then 2
     when my_column < 400 and my_column >=300 then 3
     when my_column >=400 then 4
end as Bins
from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks ! Could it be automatic process  ? For case I need first to check the data dimensions , then write the case statment

Comment: yes.i think you should look at the range of data in the column and then use `case` accordingly.

Comment: @Toren . . . If you can figure out what you mean by an "automatic process", you might want to ask another question.

Comment: I'll try : automatic process like `hist`  function in R that , if I recall correctly , automatically bining data

Comment: I tried to change `then 1` to `then one` it produce `SQL error : Unknown column one in 'field list'` . Ant idea how to fix it ?

Comment: you should use `'one'` because if you don't use quotes it would be treated as a column.